# Python parse json keyword

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, urllib

I am looking to parse some data that is requested on a webpage.

So far I have been able to configure the following.

```
import urllib.request,json

with urllib.request.urlopen("JSONURL") as url:
   data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
   print(data["live-status-local"])
```

This returns the following information

> {'status': 'error', 'status-description': 'Ingest options: {srcname=a,ratelimit=3250000}; Backend: (null); Src: File IO error; Push: Does not try to push due to recent source signal problems; ', 'status-description-debug': '', 'user-message': 'Problem with the source signal', 'status-map': {'Ingest options': {'text': '{srcname=a,ratelimit=3250000}', 'level': 'unknown'}, 'Backend': {'level': 'ok'}, 'Src': {'text': 'File IO error', 'level': 'error'}, 'Push': {'text': 'Does not try to push due to recent source signal problems', 'level': 'error'}, 'BCC Setup': {'level': 'ok', 'debug': 'Session s3 is open. '}}, 'status-data': {'session-id': 's3', 'input.bitrate': '149'}}

I want to print out/read if the 'status': 'error'

If it does so, I want the system to return stating that there is an error.

Could someone help point me in the correct direction?

Comment: You've deserialized your JSON already, you are working with Python objects. Are you asking how to use a `dict`?

Comment: `if data["live-status-local"]["status"] == "error":`

Comment: Yes, I want to specifically check for that dictionary item. I am new to Python so any pointers here would help.

Comment: If you are just starting python, then your best bet is too look at a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). This site is not meant to act as a tutorial.

Comment: @Barmar -that does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using **.json()**. With *requests* imported, try the following:

```
urlResults = requests.get("http://example.com/file.json")
data = urlResults.json()

if data["live-status-local"]["status"] == "error":
    #handle error
```